# Articulating Mount 65" led TV - 1 stud

Tags: television, mount

I would like to mount a 65" led TV on a wall where I can only hit a single stud - the studs are 24" apart and the TV weights approx 75lbs.

[This particular mount](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001LL5JDA) can extend 2FT out from the wall, and will be used in that way. We'll tilt the TV so that it actually sits kitty-corner in the room corner. I've looked for corner mounts but cannot find one which accommodates the 24" stud spacing.

The layout of the wall goes like this from left to right

```
window -> stud1 -> stud2 -> corner of the room
```

stud2 is 24" from the corner and stud1 is 24" from stud2, leaving 9" between stud1 and the window.

Plans:

1. Lag the TV mount into stud2 with 2 lag screws and use toggle bolts for the remaining holes. I fear this plan would end in my tv being smashed and my wall ripped apart.
2. I have a sheet of 3/4 oak plywood - I could cut a 12-14" wide strip and mount that from the window to the corner, and then mount the TV to that plywood. Using this plan I could hit stud1, stud2, and probably a stud near the window itself.

Will plan 2 support the weight of the TV at full extension? If so I have a couple more questions

- Should I lag the mount through the plywood into the stud where that is possible?
- How should the TV mount be secured to the plywood? large wood screws? Or would it be preferable to use toggle bolts through the plywood?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plan 2 (solid plywood) for the win. That kind of weight (with extra leverage) would be terrible in just drywall with a single stud. Speaking of leverage, if you can consider making the strip of ply a little taller (like, 2'), it should be a little more solid. (Admittedly, this might be overkill.)

In addition to getting the plywood into at least 2 studs, you'll probably hit something in the corner as well, which is good.

Where you have a stud behind, you might as well use a longer lag to catch both the ply and the stud. Where it's just drywall, I'd be comfortable using a stubby (like, 1-1/2") lag, but a sturdy toggle wouldn't be bad either. (Or you could put t-nuts on the back of the ply and use threaded bolts.)

Answer (score 1):

Plan 3: (call it the right way to structurally reinforce a wall to support lateral loads)

- Open the wall between the 2 studs, from header to toe
- leave enough wall-board 1/2 width on each stud (for taping)
- Add new stud on 12" center, secured to header and toe with plates, fully nailed
- Add fire-blocking horizontally on 24" offsets, top to bottom
- (optional) Drill studs for power, CAT-6, and cable at 6" offsets, 3ft from floor
- (optional) Add new-work multi-box on new stud at UL height above ground (per code.)
- Close wall with new wall-board patch, tape, mud. Sand, texture, paint.
- Don't forget to vacuum, or you-know-who will be upset.

Then:

- Install tilt-swivel mount on lags to 2 studs per instructions
- Connect power, cable, and IT to new-work junction box.
- relax and enjoy a job well done